# Update table based on criteria from 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a field in a table with pricing based on criteria from 4 tables.  I am trying to multiply pnm.list_price by 47%.  My select query works well to filter the records but now I need to update those identified records.

```
select mfg.mfg_code, pnm.pn, pnm.description, stk.unit_cost, stk.rec_date,  
    whs.warehouse_code, stk.qty_available, po.entry_date
from  parts_master pnm join manufacturer mfg on pnm.mfg_auto_key = mfg.mfg_auto_key
                   join warehouse whs on pnm.whs_auto_key = whs.whs_auto_key
                   join stock stk on pnm.pnm_auto_key = stk.pnm_auto_key
                   join po_detail po on pnm.pnm_auto_key = po.pnm_auto_key
where REGEXP_LIKE(mfg.mfg_code, '^[[:digit:]]+$')AND
              pnm.list_price < 3000.00 AND
              stk.qty_available > 0 AND
              pnm.list_price IS NOT NULL AND
              whs.warehouse_code = 'MI SKYLINE' AND
              po.entry_date = (select max(po.entry_date) 
                                  from po_detail)
```

Thanks for your help.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You want to `UPDATE` the parts_master table and limit the rows to the ones returned from your `SELECT` statement.

Like this:

```
UPDATE parts_master
SET list_price = list_price * 1.47
WHERE primary_key_id IN (
    select pnm.primary_key_id
    from  parts_master pnm join manufacturer mfg on pnm.mfg_auto_key = mfg.mfg_auto_key
                       join warehouse whs on pnm.whs_auto_key = whs.whs_auto_key
                       join stock stk on pnm.pnm_auto_key = stk.pnm_auto_key
                       join po_detail po on pnm.pnm_auto_key = po.pnm_auto_key
    where REGEXP_LIKE(mfg.mfg_code, '^[[:digit:]]+$')AND
                  pnm.list_price < 3000.00 AND
                  stk.qty_available > 0 AND
                  pnm.list_price IS NOT NULL AND
                  whs.warehouse_code = 'MI SKYLINE' AND
                  po.entry_date = (select max(po.entry_date) 
                                      from po_detail)
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not updating parts_master list_price.  Not sure why.  The statement looks good.  Jeff

Comment: Did you commit? Did it report how many rows have been updated? How many results does the inner query return? Are you sure you are referencing the same primary key column in the outer UPDATE and the inner SELECT?